# Can I replace tungsten-halogen lamps with an LED version?

Tags: led, halogen

I've a lamp which uses 12 bulbs of this kind, and I've very little knowledge about this kind of thing, so despite it seems feasible, I don't know what information I should look for, and what kind of LEDs (+adapter?) I should buy to replace the current ones.

The thing is that whilst current lights aren't cheap, they don't last long after opened, and I really mean it, some even are spoilt the day after, whilst they claim to last 2000 to 3000 hours (why does a light bulb stop working btw?)

[image: tungsten-halogen lamp]

Comment: This looks like a G4 socket. Just search the net for "G4 led". For the broken lamps: just look at them very closely and you'll see.

Answer (score 4):

These types of lights range in voltage from 6V to 120V depending on the fixture.
The voltage & wattage should be stamped on the glass.
These lamps usually create a large amount of heat if you install them with fingers the oil from your skin will severely reduce the bulb life.
If they come in a plastic wrapper cut the end off and install the bulb only touching the plastic, if they come loose use a tissue or paper towel to hold the bulb and install it.
This may extend your bulb life. Also if they can be put on a dimmer just slightly dropping the voltage can double the life for the 120V models.
[here is an LED replacement for 120V](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Dimmable-G4-White-Warm-White-80-LED-3014-SMD-Light-Silicone-Crystal-Bulb-Lamp-110V-220V/32469143367.html?spm=2114.40010508.4.2.Wi48iK)

Comment: If they're low wattage that's all good.  I haven't yet been able to find replacements for the higher wattage versions.  You need to compare lumen values for halogens of the wattage you buy and the LED bulbs you're thinking of, and avoid LED bulbs that don't tell you lumens.

Comment: The skin oil thing is a huge factor with these bulbs. I've been using a desklamp with one of these bulbs for the last 12 years. Most bulbs have lasted the quoted hours or longer, and one burned out the next day after installing it with bare hands.

Comment: I always install them with a piece of cloth, I never touch them directly because I knew about the oil and lifespan, but seems they don't like the cloth either :/

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find LED replacements that use the right socket (from your picture I'd guess it's a G4 socket) and voltage.

The main point of LED lamps is that they require less electrical energy (Watt) to produce the same brightness (lux/lumen/candela) as halogen lamps. This means that your replacement with comparable "lighting power" will consume less electrical power.

I once had a transformer for 12V halogen lamps that required a *minimum* wattage of the attached lamps. Make sure that your energy source for the lamps operates in it's specified conditions (or consider buying a new transformer that has no minimum wattage). I'd guess that using this transformer with LEDs instead of halogen lamps would result in an overvoltage and quickly destroy the LEDs.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working through this, and it turns out Halogen 12V lamps are normally run on 12V AC.  The LEDs expect to run on 12V DC.

So the two options are to change the power supply to a DC output, or leave one halogen in the fixture.